# AWS Pinpoint showing me a PERMANENT_FAILURE Access denied error when trying to send SMS

Tags: sms, aws-pinpoint

I am trying to send an SMS from the AWS Pinpoint console, but a "PERMANENT_FAILURE Access denied" message appears, no matter the number

[image: error showed by AWS Pinpoint]

How can I fix it?

Comment: @OliverSchenk sorry the late response. I already add a response for the question, hope it helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tuns out AWS paused our ability to send SMS messages. We checked our cases in "Support Center" section and there was a case that had a title: [ACTION REQUIRED] SMS Sending Issue for AWS. The message initially says:

> **"We have paused your ability to send SMS messages. During a review of your account we identified some issues that could cause mobile providers to identify your messages as unsolicited or problematic. Below is a sample of the problematic content."** [...]

Not sure if the problem was finally solved by the market team, but at least we, as the technical team, could sleep well knowing what the problem was.